# Receiving an error when trying to find a value by key (python)

Tags: python, json

When trying to retrieve "Q1" in my json data I am receiving the error : "string indices must be integers".

```
{  
   "ID_54321":{  
      "Name":"John Doe",
      "Email":"jdoe@gmail123.com",
      "Q1":"3"
   }
}
```

I am able to retrieve the item.

```
for key in data:
  for item in data[key]:
   print item
```

Result

```
Name
Email
Q1
```

The issue is that I cannot retrieve the value for the item I am trying to retrieve.

```
 for key in data:
      for item in data[key]:
       print item["Q1"]
```

I recieve the error :

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: Look carefully at your object types and try to figure out what the error means

Comment: Might help you to visualize if you also print `key`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While looping in `data[key]` you can get value with `data[key][item]`:

```
data = {
    "ID_54321": {
        "Name": "John Doe",
        "Email": "jdoe@gmail123.com",
        "Q1": "3"
    }
}

for key in data:
    for item in data[key]:
        print data[key][item]
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all I'm assuming you are talking about iterating over dictionary rather than JSON object, because JSON is a string representation of data  while dictionary is a data structure.

In your case "item" is a string (in fact names of the keys from nested dict) so you can't get your value from it.

If your looking just for the value of 'Q1' key you could do something like:

```py
for key in data.iterkeys():
   print data[key]['Q1']
```

But assuming you want to print each value from the nested dictionary not just 'Q1' it could be:

```
for key in data.iterkeys():
    for k, v in data[key].iteritems():
       print k, v
```

Where k is the name of each key and v is the corresponding value.

And in Python 3.X it would look like this:

```
for item in data.keys():
    for k,v in data[item].items():
        print(k,v)
```

Answer (score 0):

`item["Q1"]` gives you an error because `item` is a string. What you want to do is access the inner dictionary's key-value so try changing it to something like this:

```
for key in data:
    for item in data[key]:
        print data[key][item]
```